# How Do I create a trigger on a table that insert into another database

Tags: mysql

I have two mySQL db's on called home and the other called zenphoto_live.

I want to create a trigger on zephoto_live.zp_images that inserts a record into home.tbl_new_image_inserts when ever a new/update occurs on the zenphoto_live.zp_images table.
I tried

> CREATE    DEFINER =  CURRENT_USER  TRIGGER new_images  AFTER INSERT ON
>   zenphoto_live.zp_images  FOR EACH ROW   insert into
>   home.tbl_new_image_inserts (id,albumid,datetime) 
>       values
>   (zenphoto_live.zp_images.id,zenphoto_live.zp_images.albumid,now());

but I get "No Database selected" error.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify a full name for the trigger, e.g. -

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER zephoto_live.new_images AFTER INSERT ON
...
```

Or set default database for the session -

```
USE zephoto_live;
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER new_images AFTER INSERT ON
...
```